# How to create SAML xml for Linkedin Login

Tags: amazon-web-services, linkedin-api, saml, amazon-cognito

I am trying to integrate Linkedin login in AWS cognito. But as per AWS there is no direct method for integrating Linken in Coginto same like Google and FB. So I am trying with SAML option, but I have seen that Linkedin is not yet supporting SAML. Is there any way to integrate Linked in coginito login page along with Google and FB? Is there any way to generate SAML xml for Linkedin login.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the [guides for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you reviewed LinkedIn's oauth documentation at https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2# ?  I'm not familiar with Cognito, but would be surprised if it can't integrate with an OAuth provider.

Comment: Yes, We have already integrated using oauth2. In cognito we cannot integrate it using oauth2. Cognito is having inbuilt support for google, FB and twitter. Others we can integrate using SAML xml's.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article on how to use Linked In with Cognito.

[Cognito & LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/aws-cognito-developer-authentication-amit-kumar)